# Quicktag button to automatically add a custom field to a post

Tags: custom-field, quicktag

Is it possible to add a quicktag button to the Wordpress add post editor which when clicked will automatically assign a custom field to a post?

Sometimes I have 50 scheduled posts, 30 of which have to be marked with a custom field called "featured_on_homepage" used to indeed make the post featured in a specific place on the blog's front page.

If I could have a button to do it, I would go through the 30+ posts much more easily.

Comment: Maybe you take a look [here](http://generatewp.com/quicktags/) to create your own quicktags?

Comment: I actually know how to create them, how to insert custom HTML code in the post. What I don't know is how to call the database to insert a custom field. I could be wrong but it seems your link does not explain how to call an INSERT statement via a QuickTag call.